# C++ Passing pointer to current object to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, this

**This was a header problem, I forgot to include a header...**

We should use `getMoves(this)`

I need to send a pointer to the current object to a function but can't manage to find out how to do it... :/

**chess_piece.h**

```
class ChessPiece
{
    public:
        virtual std::list<Move *> getMoves(Chess *game) = 0;
};
```

**chess.cpp**

```
list<Move *> Chess::getMoves()
{
    ChessPiece *p;
    ...
    list<Move *> moves = p->getMoves(*this);
    // can't manage to get a pointer to the current object here
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can a get a pointer to the current object?

`this` is a `Chess* const`

`*this` gives me a `Chess&`, when I try to do this:

`list<Move *> moves = p->getMoves(*this);`

I get `no matching function for call to ‘ChessPiece::getMoves(Chess&)’`

**EDIT**

Everyone is telling me to do this:

`list<Move *> moves = p->getMoves(this);`

But I already tried and I get:

`no matching function for call to ‘ChessPiece::getMoves(Chess* const)’`

**EDIT2**

Here is my declaration of Chess::getMoves():

**chess.h**

```
class Chess : public Game
{
    public:
        std::list<Move *> getMoves();
};
```

Comment: `this` being `Chess* const` is just fine and expected.  Have you `#include`-d the header with `ChessPiece` before trying to call `p->getMoves(this)` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, of course

Comment: Well, if all that code goes into one file, the version with `this` (not `*this`) compiles just fine.  See http://ideone.com/VpNQEY  So you have some problem with header files.

Comment: @BenVoigt: but forgot to `#include` **chess.h** in **piece.h**! That was it! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getMoves(Chess *game) = 0;

getMoves take a pointer of Chess class as parameter.

> list moves = **p->getMoves(*this);**

here you are passing *this, but this itself is a pointer.

so >list moves = **p->getMoves(this);**